# Unable to remove module of node-red

Tags: node.js, module, uninstallation, node-red

I am having issues with node-red and can no longer run any flows, i am not sure what to do anymore.

i get the following error

```
Imported unrecognised type: mqtt-env-broker
Flows stopped due to missing node types. Check logs for details.
```

Tried to remove this module from the palette but get the following error, i am also unable to disable it

```
Failed to remove: node-red-contrib-mqtt-env
Error: Type in use: mqtt-env-broker
Check the log for more information
```

I have installed the node-red-admin and tried to remove it from command line, so i issued the following command

```
sudo node-red-admin remove node-red-contrib-mqtt-env/mqtt-env
```

i get the following error

```
404: Cannot DELETE /nodes/node-red-contrib-mqtt-env/mqtt-env
```

this is what i get when i ran the following command

```
node-red-admin list

Nodes                                 Types                 State
node-red-contrib-mqtt-env/mqtt-env    mqtt-env in           error
                                      mqtt-env out
                                      mqtt-env-broker
node-red-dashboard/ui_audio           ui_audio              enabled
...
...
node-red/mqtt                         mqtt in               error
                                      mqtt out
                                      mqtt-broker
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flows are stopped because they are trying to use a node type you have not got installed - or in this instance, it appears, is hitting an error when it tries to start

The runtime won't let you remove the node because it is referenced in your flow.

To fix this you need to delete any of the nodes referenced by this module from your flow. The name `mqtt-env-broker` suggests it is a configuration node rather than a regular flow node. Open the Configuration Nodes sidebar panel (from the drop-down menu) and look for any `unknown` config nodes. Double click on them and delete them. Once you've removed them, hit deploy and things should start working again.

You should then be able to delete the node module from your runtime.

Comment: Unless it's a node that has been globally installed (sudo npm install -g node-name) in which case you will need to remove it from the command line with sudo npm rm -g node-name)